# How hide and show DxTab item programmatically

Tags: javascript, tabs, devextreme

Im using js DevExtreme for evaluation.
I have a layout with dxtabbeditem with two tabs inside.
I would to change the visibility of second tabs from my javascript code, this is my layout:

```
    <DxForm>
     <DxGroupItem>
      <DxTabbedItem>
        <DxTab
         :col-count="12"
         :title="First tab">    >
         <!-- first tab -->
        </DxTab>
        <DxTab
         :col-count="12"
         :title="Second tab">    
         <!-- second tab -->
        </DxTab>
      </DxTabbedItem>
    </DxGroupItem>
   </DxForm>
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: what you are using jquery ,angular, react or vue ? Changing visibility in what sense change visibility css or you want to have some new class on desire tab ?

Comment: Im using vue js, i would change visibility to keep hidden the second tab and tho show when something happen in my code, this tab has a visible flag to set visibility but i cant able to set from code. https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxForm/Item_Types/TabbedItem/#visible